# Basic questions about SURF and tracking algorithms

Tags: opencv, implementation, tracking

When detecting objects using SURF, how can a plot a graph for false positives and hits using the Good matches and several keypoints?

**(A)** How do I get the statistics of good matches i.e an ROC plot or the true positives vs false positives of detection from so many of the line descriptors?Can somebody put a code for plotting true positves vs false positive statistics.

(B)**Secondly,there are many resources [vdo1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHT46f2244E) , [vdo2](http://robocv.blogspot.ca/2012/02/real-time-object-detection-in-opencv.html)and implemetations, papers ( [Object tracking using improved Camshift with SURF method](http://www.deepdyve.com/lp/institute-of-electrical-and-electronics-engineers/object-tracking-using-improved-camshift-with-surf-method-0EENoJXwYA/1) ;
[A Study on Moving Object Tracking Algorithm Using SURF Algorithm
and Depth Information](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2012/Istanbul/ISTISC/ISTISC-12.pdf)
) which say that SURF and SIFT can be used for tracking in combination with camshift or meanshift.

But, what I fail to understand is that we need prediction algorithm like Kalman filters or tracking algorithm like Camshift,mean shift or template differencing(not sure) for tracking.So,how come some video implementations and tutorial say that Lukas Kanade Optical flow,SIFT,SURF is tracking objects whereas the papers mention to club either camshift or meanshift.Am I missing out on some conceptual matter?

Shall be obliged for pointers and a detailed explanation on how SURF  or SIFT or feature based methods can be used for tracking alone?

Answer (score 0):

Lucas-Kandae with pyramid (pyrLK) is a method that looks for a small shift in a single feature location. It can do this to many features at once. Camshift and meanshift track a statistic for a group of features. You can also just try to use a matcher, to find where the features went on the next frame. GoodFeturesToTrack, SIFT and SURF are algorithms that find points that should be easy to find and tell apart one from another. SURF and SIFT include also descriptors, that characterise those features in a way which can ignore size change, orientation change or both.

Kalman filter is used to refine Your results. It is able to shrink the area where the answer should lay, because algorithms above are not perfect.

As for the code, I haven't done too much tracking except Shi-Thomasi + pyrLK, so I dont't think I can help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.My confusion and doubts still remain which is can SIFT or SURF alone be used for tracking as mentioned in the links (SURF based tracker) etc..the word "tracker" appended after SURF is what I am confused about since tracking would essentially need a predictor like Kalman or mean shift/camshift which is not implemented in with SURF in the links.